# File popups freeze in specific directory and show nothing - how to fix?

Tags: symlink, gtk, qt, file-management

I had this issue *for **months***. Whenever I moved to my home directory within a file popup (from both qt and gtk), the window freezed and I could neither close it nor move to another directory. I just had to `pkill` the parent window.

Running on archlinux, I decided it was some bug due to all packages being 'too much' up-to-date, so I patiently waited and every now and then upgraded the system, hoping it will be fixed.
Nope. And Google said nothing about it.

This lead me to creating symlinks between Downloads/Documents and a few other directories so that I don't have to go to `~/` from the file popup. I had to link files from `~/` to other directories and avoid any cd to it.

I was looking at the output of `ls`, inspected `.config`, deleted some weird files like `./-` (it was empty, no idea where it came from), hoping this was the root cause.

---

Does anybody know how to fix it? One could probably copy the whole directory to another place and begin a binary search & remove process until it works. If it does.

Today, out of frustration I was inspecting the home dir again. *And I found it*.
This little piece of evil. It is so absurd it could cause such trouble that I want to share my finding with you, because it cost me a lot of inconvenience and I wish it to no one.

Answer (score 0):

This is the little beast:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user users   16 Jan 19 22:06  filename -> /mnt/sdb1/VIDEO/
```

Looks like just a broken symlink, but this is not all. Because I have this:

```
$ grep sdb /etc/fstab
/dev/sdb1   /mnt/sdb1   auto  rw,noauto,x-systemd.automount 0 2
```

And everytime you reference `/mnt/sdb1`, it tries to mount it to `/dev/sdb1`. And if there's nothing plugged in and there's no `/dev/sdb1`, it freezes.